# Web Matrix Error "No default document"

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I'm new to Web matrix and Razor Syntax indeed. But unfortunately I have an error that appears in the browser when I try to run a test website.

and this is the error

"HTTP Error 404.20 - Not Found
No default document."

but when I open any pages in the site through Right Click + Lunch in browser it runs properly.

There are some suggested solutions that appeared in the browser but I couldnt benefit from them

{Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the site.
The URL contains a typographical error.
Directory browsing is not enabled. }

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From version 2, WebMatrix will look for a default document if you launch the site from the Run button or by pressing F12. You can manage default pages in the Site workspace. Click the Setting button. Otherwise, if you want to launch a specific (non-default) page, you have already discovered the way to do that - right click on it in the file explorer and choose Launch in browser.