# asp.net web pages. Default route

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

How I can set up my site (asp.net web pages) to get urldata for default page?

site.com/default/1

- this work, 
  but site.com/1 return 404 error.
  In web forms this work fine, but in web pages no

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you have a `default.cshtm`l that is always the default start page, even if it´s not listed in the list with default pages under Settings. I guess it´s because how the routing works in ASP.NET Web Pages.

If you want a `index.html` as start page, you need to add it to the list with default pages, and remove the `default.cshtml` if you have that.

see [This](http://asp.net.bigresource.com/WebMatrix-How-to-change-default-login-page-KaR6BNW57.html#gspoVjZBo) link

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
<files>
<add value="Default.htm" />
<add value="Default.asp" />
<add value="index.htm" />
<add value="index.html" />
<add value="iisstart.htm" />
<add value="default.aspx" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Here [Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872810/web-matrix-error-no-default-document)

Comment: Not helped. example   site.com---open default.cshtml. site.com/default/1 open default.cshtml with urldata-1, and site.com/1 return 404 error.

Comment: @user3384879 did you follow the `links`??

Comment: @A_Sk Please show an example, when www.mysite.com/hello123 redirects to www.mysite.com/default/hello123, where "hello123" can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, there is a file called as App_Start. You can configure RouteConfig.cs file whatever you want. There is the example of Route function :

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: I not use MVC, I use web pages(webmatrix)